# Zend Framework repeated functionality

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've recently started working with Zend Framework and I've absolutely fallen in love with it and I've even decommissioned my own framework in favour of it.

But I'm missing something that is probably so painfully obvious you'll chuckle a little bit.

I have a login system and in every controller I have to put the check for the login status, I had a look at accessing the Zend Session Storage in the Bootstrap but I'm on bit of a deadline and can't afford to waste time, is there a better way to check IE in the bootstrap? instead of repeating 20+ lines of code and functionality in every controller.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same here I am too exploring it & Zend is awesome...Btw you can look into this may helps you -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306374/show-login-form-on-every-page-using-zend-form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a controller plugin for this. See: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html

```
class Your_Plugin_Login extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        if (!Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()) {
            // send the user to the login page
            $request->setControllerName('login')
                    ->setActionName('login');
        }
    }
}
```

replace the controller/action names with whatever is appropriate for your login page, and 'Your' with your application's namespace.

You then register the plugin with the Front controller either in application.ini or in your bootstrap with `Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->registerPlugin(new Your_Plugin_Login());`.

**Edit**: If you want to put the user details in the view as well, you can do:

```
$layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
$view = $layout->getView();
$view->user = Zend_Auth::getIdentity();
```

Comment: I actually prefer this to my method - really nice, low maintenance way to mixin some functionality. Although, if there is a user logged in, how would you be able to use this method to make the user details accessible from the controller?

Comment: You can access the view object and store things in it in a similar way. I've edited my answer to include an example of this.

Comment: Here is an example of a login widget/login manager developped by the lead programmer of ZF : http://mwop.net/blog/246-Using-Action-Helpers-To-Implement-Re-Usable-Widgets which can easily be adapted to become a controller plugin

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own controller that inherits from Zend Controller (call it e.g. DaveMac_Controller - you can define the prefix in the app's config file so that the app can autoload it (and you need to be careful with which directory you save your class in)). In this class's construct function run the check for authentication. Then change all your page's controllers to inherit from DaveMac_Controller rather than the default zend one.

If I was at home I could copy and paste some code as an example, but at work right now so hopefully the above outline is enough.

*edit Good ol' dropbox :)

application.ini

```
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "DaveMac_"
```

/../library/DaveMac/Controller/Action.php

```
<?php 

class DaveMac_Controller_Action extends Zend_Controller_Action {


    protected $acl;
    protected $user;
    protected $userRole;

    public function init() {

        //retrieve and store user details
        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance(); 
        if($auth->hasIdentity()){
            $user = $auth->getIdentity();
            $this->user = $user;
            $this->view->user = $user;
            $this->userRole = $user->role;
        } else {
            $this->userRole = "guest";
        }

        //Initialise access control list
        $this->acl = new DaveMac_Acl();
    }

    protected function checkAuth($pageLevel, $redirect = "/") {
        if($this->user) {
            if(!$this->acl->isAllowed($this->userRole, $pageLevel)) {
                $this->_redirect($redirect);
            }
    } else if ($pageLevel != DaveMac_Resources::PUBLIC_ONLY_PAGE) {
        $this->_redirect('/login/returnurl/' . str_replace('/','-',$this->getRequest()->getRequestUri()));
        }
    }
}
```

You will probably already have your own functioms fdor checking authentication, but I thought I'd leave mine in anyway